# HTML Button click two at once...how to prevent

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating buttons to minimize / restore / fulscreen divs.  I have three buttons, one for min, restore/max, and close.  the close works fine, but the min and restore buttons act funny.  when I click restore the min button gets bigger and it minimizes.

```
<div id='<%= request.getParameter("id") %>' class='window'>
    <div id='header' class='header'>
        <label id='title'><%= request.getParameter("title") %></label>
        <label>
            <button id='restore' onclick='JavaScipt:Minimize<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&#95;</button>
            <button id='restore' onclick='JavaScipt:Restore<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&Dagger;</button>
            <button id='close' onclick='JavaScript:Close<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>X</button>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id='content' class='content'>

    </div>
    <div id='footer' class='footer'>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
function Minimize<%= request.getParameter("id") %>()
{
    if (minimized == false)
    {
        orig_width = $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").width();
        orig_height = $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").height();

        $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").width(200);
        $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").height(30);

        minimized = true;
    }
}

function Restore<%= request.getParameter("id") %>()
{
    if (minimized == true)
    {
        $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").width(orig_width);
        $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").height(orig_height);

        minimized = false;
    }
}

function Close<%= request.getParameter("id") %>()
{
    $("#<%= request.getParameter("id") %>").remove();
    RemoveID(<%= request.getParameter("id") %>);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was storing the buttons in a label.  Not sure why but I changed it to an inline-block div and it fixed it.

```
        <div class='buttons'>
            <button id='minimize' onclick='JavaScipt:Minimize<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&#95;</button>
            <button id='resotre' onclick='JavaScipt:Restore<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>M</button>
            <button id='close' onclick='JavaScript:Close<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>X</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well, no... the issue you described in your question was because the two buttons had the same id. Putting them in a div would've still had the same issue.

Comment: No.  This was the fix.  The clicking has nothing to do with the Id's although it is good to have unique Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Two of your buttons have the same id:

```
<label>
    <button id='resotre' onclick='JavaScipt:Minimize<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&#95;</button>
    <button id='resotre' onclick='JavaScipt:Restore<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&Dagger;</button>
    <button id='close' onclick='JavaScript:Close<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>X</button>
</label>
```

The first two buttons both have the id 'resotre'. Change one of them to 'minimize' (following your current convention), and this should behave as you expect.

```
<label>
    <button id='minimize' onclick='JavaScipt:Minimize<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&#95;</button>
    <button id='resotre' onclick='JavaScipt:Restore<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>&Dagger;</button>
    <button id='close' onclick='JavaScript:Close<%= request.getParameter("id") %>();'>X</button>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given your Restore and Minimize buttons the same html id. Id's should be unique across your document.